# Kurento not working on another machine

Tags: java, maven, lan, kurento

I'm new to kurento. I want to test the hello world example. I followed the instructions from the official website, and everything is working correctly locally. I even tried other kurento projects with no problem.

However, when i try to browse the page from a different machine (VM or another laptop) which is also on the same LAN, the remote stream is not showing.

This is written on the documentation website:
These instructions work only if Kurento Media Server is up and running in the same machine as the tutorial. However, it is possible to connect to a remote KMS in other machine, simply adding the flag kms.url to the JVM executing the demo. As we’ll be using maven, you should execute the following command

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dkms.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento
```

I tried using this command like this:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dkms.url=ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
```

Still no chance.

As for the log, the browser displays the following and hangs:

```
Page loaded ...
Starting video call ...
Creating WebRtcPeer and generating local sdp offer ...
spec: {"audio":true,"video":{"width":640,"framerate":15}}
ff37: {"audio":true,"video":{"advanced":[{"width":{"min":640,"max":640}},{"framerate":{"min":15,"max":15}}]}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: -Dkms.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento is used to configure Kurento Media Server URL (location where your media server is running).  If your media server is running in the same machine (127.0.0.1) then why you want to use kms.url ?

Comment: Also, what do the logs in your app server and KMS say?